# Passing arguments to AWS Boto3 Cognito-idp isn't recognized by the API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a new user in my Cognito user-pool. I'm using the [admin-create()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_create_user) call.

Here is my script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import argparse

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-username', dest='username')
parser.add_argument('-email', dest='email')
parser.add_argument('-phone_number', dest='phone_number')

args = parser.parse_args()

response = client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId='eu-central-aaaaaaa',
    Username=args.username,
    UserAttributes=[
        {
            'Name': 'email',
            'Value': args.email,
            'Name': 'phone_number',
            'Value': args.phone_number,
        },
    ],
    # TemporaryPassword='',
    ForceAliasCreation=False,
    MessageAction='RESEND',
    DesiredDeliveryMediums=[
        'EMAIL'
    ],
)
```

As you can see, `MessageAction=` is set to `RESEND`.

I'm running the following command: `cognito.py -username test -email test@test.com -phone_number +12345678`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminCreateUser operation: No email provided but desired delivery medium was Email
```

Similar errors can be reproduced if I try to use the `email_verified` or `phone_number_verified` attributes for the user. If I set them to true, I get errors telling me that it's not possible to verify the email/phone because it wasn't provided. But as you can clearly see, it was.

I'm trying to understand why my arguments are not getting recognized.

The weird thing is that if I change the attribute to `MessageAction='SUPPRESS'`, and also if I don't add the verify email/phone attributes, then the user IS getting created with the username, email and phone that I passed.

So just for the example, here is the working code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import argparse

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-username', dest='username')
parser.add_argument('-email', dest='email')
parser.add_argument('-phone_number', dest='phone_number')

args = parser.parse_args()

response = client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId='eu-central-aaaaaa',
    Username=args.username,
    UserAttributes=[
        {
            'Name': 'email',
            'Value': args.email,
            'Name': 'phone_number',
            'Value': args.phone_number,
        },
    ],
    # TemporaryPassword='',
    ForceAliasCreation=False,
    MessageAction='SUPPRESS',
    DesiredDeliveryMediums=[
        'EMAIL'
    ],
)
```

I can run the command again and the user will be created:

```sh
cognito.py -username test -email test@test.com -phone_number +12345678
[server]$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you need one dict per user attribute in your UserAttributes Array. You are just overwriting the email attribute with the phone number attribute in your code.

```py
response = client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId='eu-central-1_pDui4EwA8',
    Username=args.username,
    UserAttributes=[
        {
            'Name': 'email',
            'Value': args.email,
        },
        {
            'Name': 'phone_number',
            'Value': args.phone_number,
        },
    ],
    # TemporaryPassword='',
    ForceAliasCreation=False,
    MessageAction='RESEND',
    DesiredDeliveryMediums=[
        'EMAIL'
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to almost work. I get an error when I use `RESEND` but it works when the value is `SUPPRESS`. This is the error when I use `RESEND`: `botocore.errorfactory.UserNotFoundException: An error occurred (UserNotFoundException) when calling the AdminCreateUser operation: User does not exist.`

Comment: Oh that’s right. You need to omit it or set it to suppress if the user doesn’t exist yet

Comment: I see, so what would be the alternative way to register someone? I wanted the system to send the new user an email to finish registering.

Comment: Omitting it should send the email if I recall correctly.

Comment: You're a genius Andrew. Thank you, much appreciated :)